# Fermi liquid vs Fermi gas, when to use either one to model a metal?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, gas, fermi-liquids

I had been taught to consider electrons as a Fermi gas in order to calculate properties (like the heat capacity for instance) of metals even near $T=0K$.

However I'm now discovering Fermi liquids on my own and it seems that for low temperatures it is more accurate than using a Fermi gas because it does consider interactions between electrons. I fail to understand why we couldn't consider electron-electron interaction in the case of a Fermi gas and why would a liquid be more accurate. I understand the case of He$^3$ that remains liquid even near $0K$, but I am more interested in most metals instead. What do we lose by considering the electrons as behaving like a Fermi gas (considering both without and with $e^-$- $e^-$ interactions) as opposed to a Fermi liquid, near $0K$?

Comment: One should think of a Fermi liquid simply a Fermi gas with some parameters (eg effective mass) changed around. The fact that even in a strongly interacting system one can describe it as a non-interacting picture is the magic of Fermi liquid theory. With regards to considering electron-electron interactions, typically speaking treating them fully is an extremely difficult problem, so we look for ways around it (like Fermi liquid theory).

Comment: Perhaps a check at the wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_liquid_theory about Fermi liquid theory is worth a try.

Comment: Yes. And it is not like electrons condense in a liquid while they would be a gas at higher temperatures. This is not about a phase transition at all. Temperature has little to do with it. Cryogenic experiments are just a way to determine for example effective mass from the linear term in specific heat.